# Knowing file existence while forbidding opening

Tags: sharepoint-permissions

Is it possible to set a custom permission to let user able to to know the existence of files in a folder that he can access but does not allow the user to open the file?

Can this behavior be the same for search results? Which means I am able to search for files that I do not have access. I am able to know its existence but will not be to open or preview them?

Answer (score 0):

No. If the user can see it, they have *at least* View permissions which will allow them to open the file. You could password protect the file (e.g. if it is an Office document).